# Lenovo ThinkPad P51 won't boot into Windows or USB live Linux, but boots into BIOS fine,

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, bios, thinkpad

My Lenovo ThinkPad P51 won't boot into Windows or USB live Linux this morning, but boots into BIOS fine. It sees the SSD and Live Ubuntu USB on the boot menu. It's in an endless boot loop if trying to boot Windows or Live Linux.

The on-board Lenovo Diagnostics on the P51 shows no issue. It passed all tests. The BIOS has been reset to default.

The battery, the 230W AC adapter, memory sticks, the SSD containing Windows 10, and the Live USB Ubuntu 22.04 all have been verified to be fine on a ThinkPad P50.

It has been stripped down to just the motherboard with fan (repasted) and sitting on a docking station. And it's doing the same endless boot looping. The CMOS battery has been removed, too.

Any suggestions, folks?

Comment: I am not entirely convinced about the hardware.  Otherwise the Windows OS would have to be damaged (easy) and the USB would also have to be damaged.  I suppose both could happen

Comment: The other thing you could be seeing is that boot is always going to the main disk and the OS has become damaged

Comment: I tested the Windows 10 SSD and the USB Live Ubuntu 22.04 on my ThinkPad P50 again. They all boot and look fine to me.

Comment: As far as boot order, if I set the Windows 10 disk as the first boot device, the motherboard will cycle through LENOVO logo only after power button is pressed; if I set the live Ubuntu 22.04 as the first boot device, the the motherboard will cycle through LENOVO logo then GRUB2 boot menu. So yes it will respond to the BIOS boot order arrangement.

Comment: Something is wrong.  If your hardware is truly good, then your main disk apparently corrupted. But then your USB as well.

Comment: I tried several live Ubuntu USB on this ThinkPad P51 motherboard to no avail (Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, 22.04). All of them work on other thinkpads before or after my trials. I even tried the original 500GB HDD with Windows 7 came with this ThinkPad P51 laptop to no go. I booted this same Windows 7 drive on my ThinkPad P50 without any hiccups after that. So the observation show no disk corruptions on my Windows 10 drive and Live Linux USB.

Comment: You probably need to get this machine serviced..  Something is wrong.